# How do I alert when a certain value is met

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, alert

So I'm making a timer in html and javascript and I am displaying it on a button. I want to make it so that when the value of time is equal to zero, it alerts the user. Here is my code so far. btw, the code is part of the timer code.

```
      const time2=
  document.getElementById("countdown")
if(time2==0:00)
  alert("You have ran out of time, better luck next time!")
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: `0:00` is not valid javascript

Comment: The very first thing I can say is that you need the value of the `countdown` element if it's an input, textarea, select, etc. So you would call `document.getElementById("countdown").value`. Second, you need at least one of three kinds of quotes surrounding your `0:00` value which can be single quotes, double quotes, or back ticks because the value you get from an element with a value property will be a string value (in almost all instances).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a timer with a setInterval() and trigger some functionality when a value is reached, in this case the timer is cleared, i hope this helps:

```js
const createTimer = (num) => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(num)
        num--;
        if(num == 0) {
            console.log("You have ran out of time, better luck next time!")
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }, 1000)
}
createTimer(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
let div = document.getElementById('count')
let countdown = 10
let stopper = setInterval(myTimer, 1000)

function myTimer() {
  countdown--
  div.innerHTML = countdown + " seconds left"

  if (countdown == 0) {
    clearInterval(stopper)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='count'>10 seconds left</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation of a very simple Timer using a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Most important is [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) which will allow you to run a function every `x` milliseconds.

This timer uses a callback function `onUpdate(seconds)` which is called every time the timer is updated and provides the remaining seconds as a parameter. You could certainly extend on that.

It is also required to wait for the HMTL document to have loaded before trying to access the DOM using the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

```js
class Timer {
  #interval;
  #initial;
  #seconds;

  constructor(seconds, onUpdate) {
    this.#initial = seconds;
    this.#seconds = seconds;
    this.onUpdate = onUpdate;
    this.onUpdate(seconds);
  }

  start() {
    this.#interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.#seconds--;
      if (this.#seconds === 0) this.stop();
      this.onUpdate(this.#seconds);
    }, 1000);
  }

  reset() {
    this.stop();
    this.#seconds = this.#initial;
    this.onUpdate(this.#seconds);
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.#interval);
    this.onUpdate(this.#seconds);
  }
}

// wait for HTML document to load
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  const startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
  const stopBtn = document.getElementById("stop");
  const resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");

  // create a timer and assign it seconds as well as a callback function that is called every second
  const timerDiv = document.getElementById("countdown");
  const timer = new Timer(5, (seconds) => {
    // called every seconds with seconds to go as an argument
    timerDiv.textContent = `${seconds}s to go`
  })

  // add event listeners to buttons
  startBtn.addEventListener("click", () => timer.start());
  stopBtn.addEventListener("click", () => timer.stop());
  resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => timer.reset());
})
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```